# StorageFileQueryResult.GetFilesAsync() proper usage with IndexerOption in UWP

Tags: uwp, storagefile

I am wondering if the following is a bug or at best a documentation inaccuracy of the Windows Search API for a `StorageFolder`.

This is a simple UWP app which allows a user to pick a folder and scan this folder deeply to simply count the number of files.

The returned count is consistent with Windows 10's File Explorer if the folder is sitting here for a while, but inconsistent if the folder has been just copied to the C drive from another partition on my laptop. To make the issue clear I copied a folder containing **1768** video and image files into the desktop and run the app on the spot such that Windows 10 did not have the time to index the content.

The C# code (XAML is simple and can be guessed from the C# code)

```
    private async void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var folderPicker = new FolderPicker
        {
            SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop,
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail

        };

        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        _folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (_folder != null)
        {
            resultStackPanel.Children.Clear();
            var indexState = await _folder.GetIndexedStateAsync();
            bottomInfoTextBlock.Text = indexState.ToString();
            var queryOptions = new QueryOptions { FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep };
            foreach (IndexerOption indexerOption in Enum.GetValues(typeof(IndexerOption)))
            {
                queryOptions.IndexerOption = indexerOption;
                await CountFilesAsync(queryOptions);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task CountFilesAsync(QueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var textBlock = new TextBlock();
        resultStackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);

        if (!_folder.AreQueryOptionsSupported(queryOptions))
        {
            textBlock.Text = $"Query unsupported for {queryOptions.IndexerOption}";
            return;
        }
        var query = _folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

        textBlock.Text = $"{queryOptions.IndexerOption}: Wait, getting files count ...";
        var numOfFiles = (await query.GetFilesAsync()).Count;
        textBlock.Text = $"{queryOptions.IndexerOption} {numOfFiles}";
    }
}
```

I obtain the following result as I loop through the `IndexerOption` `Enum`

[image: Scan folder result]

What I expected is that the `IndexerOption.UseIndexerWhenAvailable` would return the exact count of `1768`, as it is documented as

> Use the system index for content that has been indexed and use the file system directly for content that has not been indexed.

What I worry about is that I would like to avoid using `DoNotUseIndexer` `Enum` value because of performance as I plan to retrieve thumbnails and extra properties from each the storage file, but this option is the only one that gives the correct count.

I checked out that the Photos app from Microsoft loads only a portion of the content, i.e. as if it uses `UseIndexerWhenAvailable`, but it has the capability to update itself as I wait for 1-2 minutes.

Hence I wonder if:

1) My only solution to provide the user with an accurate result is to use the `DoNotUseIndexer` `Enum` or is it possible to `UseIndexerWhenAvailable` or ideally `OnlyUseIndexerAndOptimizeForIndexedProperties` but track by some event
when Windows 10 eventually indexed all files to notify my app?

2) What is `UseIndexerWhenAvailable` actually doing? It seems inconsistent with its description

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following allows to inform the app as the file system changes. In the calling method fire the event

```
            query.ContentsChanged += Query_ContentsChanged;
```

with

```
   private async void Query_ContentsChanged(IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            var count = await sender.GetItemCountAsync();
            var textBlock = new TextBlock();
            resultStackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
            textBlock.Text = $"Changed {count} {sender.Folder.Name}";
        });
    }
```

The local variable `count` can be set as a property in the Page and, e.g. `OneWay` bound to a XAML `TextBlock.Text` with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In this way the value will be updated as Windows indexes all the files and after a minute or so the count reaches the final value of 1768. In addition, a removal or addition of files in the folder will update the UI count. The only caution is if you rename the folder at some point. In this case the app will start counting the default `SuggestedStartLocation`, which is the Desktop in my case. Hence the utility of checking `sender.Folder.Name` against the picked `_folder` (code not shown).

Comment: I just hit the very same problem! I also think that either the UseIndexerWhenAvailable enum is wrongly documented or simply isn't working as it should. Listening to the ContentsChanged event isn't really an option for me because my app shows a loading bar and is supposed to signal to the user once all files have been processed. As far as I can see, there is no way to figure out when that is the case when using the ContentsChanged event. Also, using DoNotUseIndexer is still much faster than waiting until the system indexes all files and calls the event